# How to get all elements text in sequential order

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I am getting text from table using bs4 as

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"table_class"})

headings = [i.get_text() for i in table.find("tr").find_all("td")]
```

But how can I have 2 findall in sequence? I tried below

`headings = [i.get_text() for i in table.find("tr").find_all("td").find_all("div")]`

If I just use `find("td")` I get only one value not all values from table.
How can I loop through `"td"` and for every element get `"div"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a problem involving iterables/iterators, look in itertools.

```
from itertools import chain

headings = [i.get_text() for i in chain.from_iterable(x.find_all("div") for x in table.find("tr").find_all("td"))]
```

Comment: @user2661518 It's really hard to test without actual test data. I assumed there was this table, in whose first `tr` there's several `td`s which each contain `div`s, right?

Comment: it works perfectly but can you iterate through multiple iterables? `"tr"` is under `"thead"` so can I do something like `find_all("tr")` under `find_all("thead")`

Comment: @user2661518 You mean just normal `chain`?

Comment: so `tr` is under `thead` I have 3 `thead` rows but above is only getting output of first `thead` how can get all 3?

Comment: sorry I just realized `div` is only under first row that's why it wasn't giving any output

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler and more concise way - a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[elm.get_text() for elm in soup.select("table.table_class tr td div")]
```

Comment: can I iterate through multiple iterables? `"tr"` is under `"thead"` so can I do something like `soup.select("table.table_class thead tr td div")]`. I tried this but it only prints one row

Comment: @user2661518 `table.table_class tr td div` - this would iterate through every `tr` in the table including the `tr` row in the `thead`. `table.table_class thead tr td div` gets you a single row since there is a single row in the table head..

Comment: @alexce yes I have 3 rows each starts with `"thead"` but above is giving me only one row. Can I get all 3 rows? sorry I'm new to CSS

Comment: @user2661518 could you please share a url to the page, or may be a relevant part of the HTML so I can experiment with it? Thanks!

Comment: sorry I just realized `div` is only under first row that's why it wasn't giving any output